# Validating a list of dictionaries of names and tags

Tags: python, validation, type-safety

I created a Python function to check the types from a list and also check the keys inside an dictionary within that list.

I have the following data:

```
[
   dict(name='Frank', tags=['dog', 'cat']), 
   dict(name='Manfred', tags=['cat', 'chicken'])
]
```

My function looks like this:

```
def _validate_data(self, data):
    if not isinstance(data, list):
        raise('not a list')
    else:
        for element in data:
            if not isinstance(element, dict):
                raise('not a dictionary')
            else:
                if not all(key in element for key in ('name', 'tags')):
                    raise('Keys not inside dictionary')
```

This works fine, but I don't like the structure and I also think there may be a smarter way to code this function. I hope someone could give me some nice and helpful hints.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There're some modules that might help you get rid of the *structure* you're complaining about like [marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [voluptous](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/voluptuous) and since you didn't added the *reinventing-the wheel* tag I guess that's perfectly okay.

For the sake of example, I'll refer to the former one because IMO it better fits our purpose (and is also probably clearer).

**From the docs:**

> Marshmallow is an ORM/ODM/framework-agnostic library for converting
>   complex datatypes, such as objects, to and from native Python
>   datatypes.
>
> In short, marshmallow schemas can be used to:
>
> 1. Validate input data.
> 2. Deserialize input data to app-level objects.
> 3. Serialize app-level objects to primitive Python types. The serialized objects can then be rendered to standard formats such as
>      JSON for use in an HTTP API.

First of, you'll need to define your Schema:

```
class DataSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.String(required=True)
    tags = fields.List(fields.String(), required=True)
```

In the above, `name` and `tags` are the keys of our dictionaries. In our class I've specified each key type (`str` and `list`). They're also mandatory, so I added `required=True`.

Next, to validate our top-level list, we need to instantiate our list item schema with `many=True` argument and then just load the data we need:

```
data, errors = DataSchema(many=True).load([
    {'name': 'Frank', 'tags': ['dog', 'cat']},
    {'name': 'Manfred', 'tags': ['dog', 'chicken']}
])
```

Printing the above:

```
print(data)
print(errors)
```

Will have the following output:

> ```
> [{'name': 'Frank', 'tags': ['dog', 'cat']}, {'name': 'Manfred', 'tags': ['dog', 'chicken']}]
> {}
> ```

Now, if we try to pass an invalid data to our dict, the `errors` will warn us about this. For example, passing a `str` instead of a list in our `tags` key will result in:

> ```
> [{'name': 'Frank'}, {'name': 'Manfred', 'tags': ['dog', 'chicken']}]
> {0: {'tags': ['Not a valid list.']}}
> ```

#### Full code:

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields


class DataSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.String(required=True)
    tags = fields.List(fields.String(), required=True)

data, errors = DataSchema(many=True).load([
    {'name': 'Frank', 'tags': ['dog', 'cat']},
    {'name': 'Manfred', 'tags': ['dog', 'chicken']}
])
```

Now, IDK if the above will be valid for all the test-cases (e.g it might allow you to pass an empty list), but it should give you a good overview of what you can achieve with this module.